# Is suppressing backflow physically realistic?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

There are some approaches in Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) to prevent backflow in inlet and outlet boundaries, such as adjusting the pressure at the boundary or extending the computational domain until backflow is suppressed.

Are these approaches physically realistic? Or are they just procedures to facilitate the convergence of the numerical solution (which can lead to results that are physically wrong)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether backflow could occur as a numerical artifact, but it could certainly occur physically under the right conditions. For example, consider the purging of a room full of warm air with a high-level and low-level opening by buoyancy forces alone. At some point in the purging process, cool air will start to enter through the high-level 'exhaust' opening at the same time as warm air exits, i.e. backflow.

[image]

Figure 1c from ['Unbalanced exchange flow and its implications for the night cooling of buildings by displacement ventilation', Wise & Hunt (2021)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10652-021-09785-7)

If a CFD model of the purging process had specified the high-level opening as an outflow opening only, then this backflow phenomenon, known as unbalanced exchange flow, could never occur.